# In Corona SDK how can I put a score keeper into my app?

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, coronasdk

I want the game I'm making to add 1 point to the score every time the ball hits the paddle.(its a pong game)  I would also like the game to save highscores.  This is the only element of the game I haven't made yet.  If anyone could help that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve your problem in a easier way..

Just declare a Variable for the Score like this..

`local score=0`

Then Increment the score variable by 1 whenever it hits the paddle. So Insert the coding in Collision Function as given below:

```
local function onCollision(event)
{
score=score+1
}
ball.collision=onCollision
ball:addEventListener("collision",ball)
```

Finally When you need to save your highscore (after gameover), You can use Preference instead of json which makes the larger coding.

```
local preference= require "preference"
local highscore=0

preference.save{highscore=score}
```

If you want to display the Highscore, then use the following:

```
highscore_value=preference.getValue("highscore")
display.newText(highscore_value,0,0,nil,30)
```

This might be useful for your problem !!

Answer (score 1):

You can save the highscores to json files.

Here's a demo:

```
local json = require"json"

----------------------------------------------------------------
local M = {} --- useful functions
function M.load_json_from_file(ffn)
    if ffn == nil then return nil end
    local fhd = io.open(ffn, "rb")
    if fhd ~= nil then
        local contents = fhd:read("*a")
        fhd:close()
        return M.formatTable(json.decode(contents))
    else
        return nil
    end
end

function M.save_json_to_file(filepath, _table)
    local fhd = io.open(filepath, "wb")
    if fhd == nil then return false end
    local string4save = json.encode(_table)
    fhd:write(string4save)
    fhd:write("\r\n")
    fhd:close()
    return true
end

function M.formatTable(t)
    local arr = {}
    for k, v in pairs(t) do
        local num_k = tonumber(k)
        if type(v) == "table" then
            if num_k ~= nil then
                arr[num_k] = M.formatTable(v)
            else
                arr[k] = M.formatTable(v)
            end
        else
            if num_k ~= nil then
                arr[num_k] = v
            else
                arr[k] = v
            end
        end
    end
    return arr
end

------------------------------------------------------------------
local test_arr = {
    [2] = 34,
    [7] = "asd",
    str = "asas"
}

local fn = system.pathForFile("test.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory)
local is_succeed = M.save_json_to_file(fn, test_arr)
print("is_succeed", is_succeed)
local read_json_from_file = M.load_json_from_file(fn)

for k, v in pairs(read_json_from_file) do
    if test_arr[k]~=v then
        print("not equal")
    end
end
```